# Looking for name of Soundwave's Autobot counterpart

Tags: character-identification, transformers

In the 1986 movie I saw at least one Autobot who, like Soundwave, turned into a cassette player and had several 'cassette' Autobots as well (I also saw the toys for these guys in a transformer catalogue) does anybody know the name of the Cassette Player Autobot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [**Blaster**](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Blaster_(G1))

> Developing a rivalry with his Decepticon opposite number, Soundwave, Blaster gained a cassette army of his own so he could fight Soundwave on equal footing
>
> [image]